# How do I return the members having admin permissions?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am making the server-info command, and I would like to add the "list of members having admin privileges". Is there any syntax for that?

Answer (score 1):

You should show code that you've tried on your post

```js
const adminMembers = <Guild>.members.cache.filter(e => e.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR"));

const array = adminMembers.map(e => e.user.tag).array();
const str = array.join("\n");
```

Comment: Why did you put Guild as <Guild>?

Comment: It represents an instance of a Guild class, this way regardless of how you get the instance, you can still use it.

Comment: So so I want to embed it and display it in the field. `.addField('Admin Privs', `${guide.members.cache.filter(e => e.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR"))}`, true)`. I get an error when I do <Guild>, and if it put guild it says guide not defined.

Comment: that's because you need a reference to guild.Obviously `<Guild>`  won't work. If you are running that function inside of a command, use your message variable and use `message.guild`, or maybe you named it `msg` => `msg.guild`. This seems more like a lack of js knowledge issue rather than discord.js, I recommend brushing up before using any library

Comment: No problem, make sure to accept the answer if it solved your problem, I see a lot of your questions that have been answered but you have not accepted.